# Not able to log into wordpress website.... self hosting on Azure

Tags: wordpress, azure, phpmyadmin, cpanel

When I try to sign into my websites wp-admin login screen it refreshes and redirects me to the login page. After researching this issue it looks like deactivating the plugins should fix the issue. However, when I try doing this from phpmyAdmin, it tells me that the UPDATE command is denied to user.

I have tried using the FTP client 'Fire FTP' to try and access my files but I do not know which username and password needs to be used (I have about a million at this point).

**Is there somewhere in the Azure portal where I can edit my files and deactivate the plugins?**

Other information: I accidentally deleted the file the had my Wordpress admin password, but I am able to log into Azure, and phpmyAdmin. I also have my cPanel login information but I cannot figure out how to access that either. I am also using a Mac.

Please help! I have a basic understanding of web development but not much and I have worked incredibly hard on my website business but this has been a rough setback.

Answer (score 1):

Looking at your problem, FTP is your best option. You can define the user/password at the portal in your app service blade:

- Login into the portal: https://portal.azure.com
- Navigate to your app service blade
- Look for Deployment Credentials and set your username/password.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I was able to resolve this. Turns out I had exceeded my database storage. Simply upgrading my plan fixed the issue. So if anyone sees this and has the same problem, make sue that your SQL db has enough storage available.

The plugins made me exceed my storage but I did not need to deactivate them.